# How can I cannot index into the values list of reduce?

Tags: mapreduce, mrjob

I am using in-mapper combining in a Map Reduce job via the Python mrjob module. Because I wrote a mapper_final function that emits a single pair, I am sure that only a single key-value pair is emitted to my reducers.

However, my reduce function is erring:

```
  def reducer(self, key, occurrences):
    '''
    Calculates the final value.
    '''
    yield 'Final Value: ', occurrences[0] / 2
```

The error reads

```
File "calculateFinalValue.py", line 354, in reducer
    yield 'Final Value: ', occurrences[0] / 2
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Why can I not index into `occurrences`? There should only be a single pair in that list, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`occurrences` is not a `list`, it is a [`generator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). If you want a `list`, you need to assemble the generator results into a list. Something like:

```
list_occurrences = [ occ for occ in occurrences ]
```

or

```
list_occurrences = list(occurrences)

yield 'Final Value: ', list_occurrences[0] / 2
```

Or you can get the first value of occurrences with `occurrences.next()`:

```
yield 'Final Value: ', occurrences.next() / 2
```