# NetworkX largest component no longer working?

Tags: python, networkx

according to networkx documentation, connected_component_subgraphs(G) returns a sorted list of all components. Thus the very first one should be the largest component.

However, when I try to get the largest component of a graph G using the example code on the documentation page

```
G=nx.path_graph(4)
G.add_edge(5,6)
H=nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)[0]
```

I get

```
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

It used to work on my other computer with earlier versions of networkx (1.7 I think, not 100% sure)

Now I am using a different computer with python 2.7.7 and networkx 1.9. Is it a version problem?

I have written a small function with a couple lines myself to find the largest component, just wondering why this error came out.

BTW, I can get the components by converting the generator object to a list.

```
components = [comp for comp in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

But the list is not sorted by component size as stated in the documentation.

example:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(4,5)])
G.add_nodes_from(range(6,20))
components = [comp for comp in nx.connected_components(G)]
component_size = [len(comp) for comp in components]
print G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges(), component_size

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1000,2000),(1000,3000),(4000,5000)])
G.add_nodes_from(range(6,20))
components = [comp for comp in nx.connected_components(G)]
component_size = [len(comp) for comp in components]
print G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges(), component_size
```

output:

```
19 3 [3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
19 3 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

looks like when the node names are large numbers and when there are a bunch of single nodes, the returned subgraphs are not sorted properly

Comment: The components in your example are returned in order of size (largest to smallest) on my machine, using NetworkX 1.9. This matches [the documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs) which says the components will be returned in descending order by size.

Comment: Aside: if you want to materialize a generator into a `list`, simply call `list`, e.g. `list(nx.connected_components(G))`.  If you only want the first element yielded by the generator, you can use `next`, e.g. `next(nx.connected_components(G))`.

Comment: Thanks @DSM! I found how to get elements from generator here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556090/how-can-i-cannot-index-into-the-values-list-of-reduce

Comment: @mdml I edited my post to put in an example

Comment: @sophiadw: the example in your post also works perfectly for me.

Comment: `print pkg_resources.get_distribution("networkx").version` gives me 1.9rc1, did I get the wrong version?

Comment: btw, do you get error msg when using `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)[0]`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The networkx-1.9 documentation is here http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components

The interface was changed to return a generator (as you figured out).  The example in the documentation shows how to do what you ask.

Generate a sorted list of connected components, largest first.

```
>> G = nx.path_graph(4)
>>> G.add_path([10, 11, 12])
>>> sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key = len, reverse=True)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]]
```

or

```
>>> sorted(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key = len, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! so the sorted feature IS taken away in 1.9

Comment: Yes, the connected components functions now longer return lists or sorted lists.  The change is documented here http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/api_1.9.html#miscellaneous-changes

Comment: Just run into this. I expected to get actual components (immediately accessible), not a "generators". Having to go through `sorted` is quite unintuitive, so thanks for the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105849/194586 provides a more efficient method if you just want the giant (largest) component: replace `sorted(..., reverse=True)` with `max(...)`. `max()` also takes a `key` kwarg which you'd keep as `len`.

Answer (score 6):

As for version 2.4:
`nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)` is removed.

Instead to get the same result use:

```
connected_subgraphs = [G.subgraph(cc) for cc in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

And to get the giant component:

```
gcc = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
giantC = G.subgraph(gcc)
```