# How do I get the giant component of a NetworkX graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I don't know if NetworkX recently tweaked one of the methods to be a generator instead of returning a list, but I'm looking for a good (rather, better) way to get the GC of a graph.

I have a working, but really inefficient-looking, snippet down:

```
# G = nx.Graph()
giant = sorted(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len, reverse=True)[0]
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In networkx 1.9, `connected_components_subgraphs` returns an iterator (instead of a sorted list). The values yielded by the iterator are [not in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378179/190597). So to find the largest, use `max`:

```
giant = max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len)
```

Sorting is O(n log n). Taking the max is O(n).

Comment: Didn't know you could use a `key` argument with `max`, interesting... Is the `connected_component_subgraphs` method the best method to use within NX?

Comment: Yes. That's the way [recommended by the main developer of networkx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24378179/190597).

Comment: Would it be possible to sort `nx.connected_component_subgraphs()` to identify not the biggest component but *all* of them? By sorting it we could end up with an **inefficient snippet** as pointed out by the OP. Is there any workaround, especially for the case of **huge networks**?

Comment: This appears to no longer work in version 2.4.  (see deprecations in https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.4.html?highlight=connected_component_subgraphs).

Answer (score 39):

In networkx 2.4, `nx.connected_component_subgraphs()` is deprecated, so the following should work:

```
Gcc = sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)
G0 = G.subgraph(Gcc[0])
```

G0 is the giant component.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only place on the internet where I could find that you need the `subgraph` method in order to extract the largest component. Note that in this case `G.subgraph(max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len))` would be faster.

Comment: @IanS thanks for the solution. Documentation does not mention that the returned component is just a set of nodes, not a sub-graph
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to keep node attributes in the newer versions since copy=True is deprecated...