# How to locate the center node of a giant component in NetworkX?

Tags: python, numpy, graph-theory, networkx

I am working with a regular network which has the shape of a 2D grid. It is made of `NxN=100x100=10000` nodes. It has a coordinate system where `node 0` is in the top left corner, the `(0,0)` position, and `node 10000` is in the bottom right corner, the `(100,100)` position.

The network is created like this:

```
N=100 #The number of nodes per side
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() ) #Dictionary of all positions
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'pos', pos) #Store pos attributes in the nodes
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'labels', labels) #Store labels attributes in the nodes
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'),
                 labels=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'labels'),
                 with_labels=False, node_size=10)
```

This network gets fragmented as a result of its response to a number of loadings. These are a number of `csv` files which values are used as input for the nodes. After the failure, this is what the network looks like (this is the result of a single loading file):

[image]

**My question:** how can I determine the location of the **center node** of the **giant component**, and determine its distance from the top left corner, for instance, which has coordinates `(0,0)`?

**EDIT**

Due to the variability in response, very rarely there will be a node at position `(0,0)`, so using `nx.shortest_path()` would be pointless in that the said node will be most of the times missing. Therefore,  I want to measure the distance between one point of the network (the center of the giant component), and another point of the same "region", which may not be part of the network. So, the function `nx.shortest_path()` cannot be used, or it would throw an `error` when the path does not exist.

Comment: Would you explain what do you mean by a center node? because the fragmented component is not regular any more.

Comment: Yes, it is an irregular shape. Therefore, by center node I mean the **visual center node** of the giant component. To give you an example, think of the visual center node as the **center of mass**. This would be "the unique point where the weighted relative position of the distributed mass sums to zero or the point where if a force is applied causes it to move in direction of force without rotation."

Comment: Well, actually I think we could write a script where the center of mass of the giant component is calculated... do you think it is feasible?

Comment: Ah okay got it, but you might have more than one center node. Also, in this case you do not change the keys of the node as before. I mean you leave them as (i,j) and not 'n'

Comment: I actually don't care what node is the real center. Something like the `(i,j)` coordinates of the center would be perfect. I don't need to identify which node is the center, but just the **position** of the center. This way I get rid of the problem of having multiple central nodes. Agree? Also, if the `(i,j)` values were float, they could always be turned into `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First retrieve the giant component of you graph with: ([referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105764/how-do-i-get-the-giant-component-of-a-networkx-graph))

  `giant = max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len)`
- Retrieve the center nodes with:

  `center_nodes = center(giant)`
- The location of the node is the center node itself because the keys are the locations. So to display the location of center nodes for instance:

  `print center_nodes`
- To determine the distance from node one of the center nodes to (i,j) coordinates, you have to keep a copy of the original graph with all the 100x100 nodes. I will use it here as `org_G`

  ```
  # i,j can represent any coordinate in the 100x100 grid (0,0) for instance
  n = (i,j) 
  print nx.shortest_path(org_G,n,center_nodes[0])
  ```

Comment: Your last point: 1) Why do you mention "node one of the center nodes"? 2) Doesn't the `nx.shortest_path()` function imply that there is a connection between my center node and point `(0,0)`? In the majority of my cases, there is no node at position `(0,0)`. So there would be no connection.

Comment: I mention node 1 because you said it does not matter which node you take as central. So I just took it as an instance.

Comment: As for the (0,0) node I thought you wanted to get the shortest path to that node. So you have to check first if  the node exists and catch exception if there is no path between the center node and (0,0)

Comment: But I assume that you meant the upper left most node in the giant component. Is that right ?

Comment: I might have made things not clear, sorry. The distance I want to measure is from the center of the giant component to a specific point in the "region" where the network is. For instance, this point could be in the top left corner (position `(0,0)`). Very rarely will there be a node in the `(0,0)` position.

Comment: So you will choose the coordinate of that point right ? I mean it can be any node

Comment: Yes, it can be any pair of coordinates. `(0,0)` was just taken as an example.

Comment: There is still something unclear I guess, so please check my EDIT. Point `(0,0)` does not have to belong to the network. I want to measure the distance between one point of the network (the center of the giant component), and another point of the same "region", which may not be part of the network. So, the function `nx.shortest_path()` cannot be used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95121/discussion-between-abdallah-sobehy-and-francesco-castellani).