# Draw individual components in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to draw just the largest components in networkx.

I've seen this [How do I get the giant component of a NetworkX graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105764/how-do-i-get-the-giant-component-of-a-networkx-graph) so can get the largest component(s). But having trouble working out how to then draw the largest n components in separate charts.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that plots the largest `n` with `n=10`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
G=nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(1000,0.002)
n=10
largest_components=sorted(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len, reverse=True)[:n]
for index,component in enumerate(largest_components):
    nx.draw(component)
    nx.savefig('fig{}.pdf'.format(index))
    plt.clf()
```

Comment: that's perfect - thanks for your help (yet again) Joel and for taking the time