# How to find the largest connected area of a graph or matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have struggled with this for a few days, and in the Python there is no way to do "int [][]" for a matrix in JAVA. My first thought is to use DFS method to exhaust the path. In the program, I set a path for the recursion. However, there is no way to always have a path, it means I have to iterate all the other nodes in the graph provided. I am new to programming, the code might be WET.

My idea is:

1. If the current vertex equals to 1, use DFS to exhaust the path and count it if there's a path.
2. If the current vertex equals to 0, find the next node and repeat the first step.

Here is my code(incomplete)

```
def dfs_explore(graph, current_vertex, visited_x= None, visited_y = None):
if visited_x is None:
    visited_x = []
if visited_x is None:
    visited_y = []

stack_x = []
stack_y = []

rows = len(graph)
cols = len(graph[0]) if rows else 0

if not (visited_x and visted_y):
    for x in range(cols):
        for y in range(rows):
            if graph[x][y] != 0:
                stack_x.append(x) # the column neighbours
                stack_y.append(y)
                visited.append(x)
                visited.append(y)
                path = dfs_explore(graph, graph[x][y], visited_x, visited_y)
                if path:
                    return path
                else not path:
                    stack_x.pop()
                    stack_y.pop()
```

Comment: Did you look at NetworkX https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html

Comment: In Python you could use something like  `int [][]` by defining a Numpy array with data type integer, if you really need it.

Comment: What is the largest connected area? Please add more details. The largest single polygon in your graph?

Comment: @Joe it's the area of the adjacency list. Sorry that I forgot to add it in the code.
the major problem now is I need to have a "visited" list to add the iterated node.

for example:

G = [[1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 0]]

I want to append the node (1, 1) because it's 1.

and the largest areas are connected with its up, down, left, and right

Comment: like this
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-connected-component-on-a-grid/

Comment: For a very simple solution you could just use the Java code with a nested list. Then you can keep lots of the code intact, removing the types, fix the loops. Thats probably not the easiest way but should work.

Comment: You could try NetworkX, see https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html

Comment: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_giant_component.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105764/how-do-i-get-the-giant-component-of-a-networkx-graph

Comment: Look for convex hull area.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert the Java code from the example
one possibility is to use Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

dim_x = 5
dim_y = 4

#initialize with zeros
visited = np.zeros((dim_y, dim_x))

visited[3][3] = 1

print(visited)
```

Another option is to use a simple nested list ("2d list"):

```
dim_x = 5
dim_y = 4

#initialize with zeros
visited = [[0 for _x in range(dim_x)] for _y in range(dim_y)]

visited[3][3] = 1

print(visited)
```

You could take a look at NetworkX. There are functions to seem to do what you need, e.g. [connected_component_subgraphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html) ([Example 1](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_giant_component.html), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105764/how-do-i-get-the-giant-component-of-a-networkx-graph))

You might need a function to calculate the *convex hull* of the nodes, there are several available, but I am not sure if there is one in NetworkX.

Comment: thanks for replying. I've already seen how it works to use "np" and nested loops.